# Filtering reverse forein key set in django

Tags: django

```
class item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class itemTxns(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(item)
    txnDate = models.DateField()
    txn = models.CharField()
```

Given an "item" object, how do I find the most recent itemTxn associated with that item?

I know I have access to item.itemTxns_set, but is it possible to query that without explicitly calling another get on the itemTxns class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
item.itemtxns_set.latest('txnDate')
```

I'm not sure how you'll get around calling it.

You could make it a property of the item class.

```
class item(models.Model):
    #....
    @property
    def latest_itemtxns(self):
        return self.itemtxns_set.latest('txndate')
```

By the way I recommend you capitalize your classes to differentiate between instances, variables, and classes.